# Java Raw Types (ex. List vs List<Object> )

Tags: java, list, object, generics, collections

Our applications have hundreds of warnings for "xxx is a raw type. References to generic type xxx<> should be parameterized"

My question, is it safe to simply set the type to Object in those places where the type is not specified?

Some examples:

```
List list = new List();
Iterator i;
```

change to:

```
List<Object> = new ArrayList<Object>();
Iterator<Object> i;
```

Comment: that's equivalently, isn't it?

Comment: If you are running Java 1.5 or later version in your production environment, this is completely ok

Comment: btw new List() is wrong.  You cannot instantiate an abstract class or interface.

Comment: I would say yes it is safe, but from the other hand. is it any good reason why you have a list of `Object`'s

Comment: there are differences. but for `List`, it mostly works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will achieve the same result, as `Object` is at the top of inheritance chain and raw types act as `Object` types.

The only caveat is that you will then need to compile and run with Java 5 or higher.

You can always `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` otherwise.

Comment: The OP is asking if it is safe to perform such an "easy" change.  I doubt it is, precisely because the warning is advicing him/her to chose the types carefully, not generally.

Comment: @LittleSanti It **is** safe, because it's equivalent. I am not saying changing parametrized types as `Object`s is ideal functionally (instead of using proper types), only that it's safe.

Comment: I've included in my post a paragraph demonstrating why it is not always safe to replace raw types by explic Object types.

Answer (score 1):

If **all** your usages of `List` (and other generalizable classes) are raw usages, yes, it's safe.

If your code mixed generelized definitions with raw definitions, you mut exercise some caution. A raw class can be used instead of any generelized class, but not vise-versa. So, for example, if you have a method with a `List<String>` parameter that you're currently passing a raw `List` to, changing it to `List<Object>` will break your compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always possible if the generic variable is type-bound. For example, if you have `MyType<T extends Number>`, replacing the `MyType` with `MyType<Object>` will result in compilation error.

Also note that adding `<Object>` you just get rid of warnings, not actually making your code safer.

Comment: @bayou.io, more complex cases may occur. For example `MyType<T extends Number> implements List<T>` and all the lists are already converted to `List<Object>`.

Comment: the question then becomes whether it's safe to *forcefully* cast `MyType` to `List<Object>`....

Answer (score 0):

No. Because Object isn't functionally usable for anything. Even although you convert your raw types to Object-based, sooner or later in your code, you'll need to perform a cast to convert those plain Objects to something more meaningful in your program. And the generics were conceived precisely to allow the programmer to *avoid casts in the code*, because a cast is performed *dinamically* (so, if it fails, you won't notice until execution). Instead, generic types are checked during *compilation*, ensuring that all the types in the program are coherent and won't produce any ClassCastExceptions in execution.

**Why it is not always safe to replace raw types by explic Object types:**

Suppose we have an old style container:

```
public class MyProvider
{
    private List list;

    public List getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List list)
    {
        this.list=list;
    }
}
```

And a client class (which might be in another library and be dependent of your code, still not under your control):

```
public class MyClient
{
    public void test()
    {
        MyProvider provider=new MyProvider();
        List<String> myList1=new ArrayList<String>();
        provider.setList(myList1);
        List<String> myList2=provider.getList();
    }
}
```

This scheme produces warnings in both provider and client, still compiles and executes OK.

But if we change the provider's public API to be Object-based:

```
public class MyProvider
{
    private List<Object> list;

    public List<Object> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Object> list)
    {
        this.list=list;
    }
}
```

... the provider part will drop all of its warnings and compile OK, but the client part will rise **compilation errors**.

Moral: **Never change public APIs if there can be some dependant, third-parrty code out of your control.**

Answer (score 0):

It is completely alright, **but** if the list contains values of different types(i.e. Booleans with Strings), you may have casting errors in your code. Simple example: if you add a boolean and a string you'll get and `ClassCastException` when you try to print it on the console:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
l.add("My string"); // Completely fine!
l.add(true); // fine
System.out.println(l.get(0)); // will output 'My string'
System.out.println(l.get(1)); // will raise ClassCastException
```